# Validating if one attribute is equal to the other in Rails 4

Tags: validation, model, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two rails models: a game model, which belongs to a winner (player model) and a loser (player model). I keep track of the `:winner_id`, `:loser_id,` and `:challenger_id`, which are used as foreign keys in the player model. When the game is created, I've made sure to validate if the winners and losers exist, but how would I validate that the challenger was a player in the game?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my problem by adding a `validate :challenger_played_in_game` at the top of my Game model, and defining the method as

```
  def challenger_played_in_game
    if(self.winner_id != self.challenger_id and self.loser_id != self.challenger_id)
        errors.add(:challenger_id, "Challenger must have played in game")
    end
  end
```